# How to bridge between faces which their distance is less than a tolerance?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a complex geometry. At some points there are very narrow gaps between faces (like the attached picture).
 I would like to define a tolerance, and bridge between faces that their distance is less than the tolerance. is this possible in Blender?

thanks,

Bp[image]

Comment: Please use screenshots instead of a picture of your screen to give clearer images of what you're working with. Ctrl + F3 will do this in Blender.

Comment: What is making the geometry, Curve or Mesh? How are you editing, with mouse or with python? Is it 6:15 when you took the picture?